# Multiprocessing a for loop with multiple arguments which depend on loop index

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Hello I want to multiprocess a for loop where i calculate 4 different independent functions. The only problem is these functions take multiple arguments. Some of these arguments are lists where I select the correct element using the loop index. Here is an example code

```
import numpy as np

def function_1(a,b,c,d):
    #do heavy calculations
    #function is written in fortran and linked via f2py
def function_2(a,b,c,d):
    #do heavy calculations
    #function is written in fortran and linked via f2py
def function_3(a,b,c,d):
    #do heavy calculations
    #function is written in fortran and linked via f2py
def function_4(a,b,c,d):
    #do heavy calculations
    #function is written in fortran and linked via f2py
result_1 = 0
result_2 = 0
result_3 = 0
result_4 = 0
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = 2
d = 5
for k in xrange(3):
    result_1 += function_1(a[k],b[k],k*c,d)
    result_2 += function_2(a[k],b[k],k*c,d)
    result_3 += function_3(a[k],b[k],k*c,d)
    result_4 += function_4(a[k],b[k],k*c,d)
```

Is there a way to do these calculations parallel rather than sequential?
Is it possible to do this for functions that are written in fortran?

Answer (score 0):

```
def gen_func(idx, *args):
  def function_1(*args):
    i_want_2 = args[:2]
    return sum(i_want_2)
  def function_2(*args):
    i_want_3 = args[:3]
    return sum(i_want_3)
  def function_3(*args):
    return sum(args)
  def function_4(*args):
    return sum(args)

  result = 0 
  func = {0:function_1,1:function_2,2:function_3,3:function_4}
  for a_k, b_k in zip(args[0], args[1]):
    result += func[idx](a_k, b_k,*args[2:])

  print idx, result




import multiprocessing
  jobs = []
  a = [1,2,3]
  b = [4,5,6]
  c = 2
  d = 5
  for i in range(4):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen_func, args=(i,a,b,c,d,))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
```

output:

```
0 21
1 27
2 42
3 42
```

Comment: This would only work if my functions have the same number of arguments right?

Comment: @chris you could change arguments to *args

Comment: Ok but that means i would have to rewrite my fortran functions to get the gen_func

Comment: @chris gen_func just a wrapper. the functions for gen_func are [re-process incoming args and select which function you want to call

Answer (score 0):

I am just thinking if it would not be easier to do something like:

```
import numpy as np

def function_1(a,b,c,d):
    #do heavy calculations
    #function is written in fortran and linked via f2py
def function_2(a,b,c,d):
    #do heavy calculations
    #function is written in fortran and linked via f2py
def function_3(a,b,c,d):
    #do heavy calculations
    #function is written in fortran and linked via f2py
def function_4(a,b,c,d):
    #do heavy calculations
    #function is written in fortran and linked via f2py
result_1 = 0
result_2 = 0
result_3 = 0
result_4 = 0
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6] 
c = 2
d = 5
for k in xrange(3):
    p_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = function_1, (a[k],b[k],k*c,d))
    p_1.start()
    p_2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = function_2, (a[k],b[k],k*c,d))
    p_2.start()
    p_3 = multiprocessing.Process(target = function_3, (a[k],b[k],k*c,d))
    p_3.start()
    p_4 = multiprocessing.Process(target = function_4, (a[k],b[k],k*c,d))
    p_4.start()
    #wait till process finishes is there such an option?
    result_1 += p_1
    result_2 += p_2
    result_3 += p_3
    result_4 += p_4
    #does the process return a complex number?
```